# Is it possible to insert multiple objects at once in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel

My co-worker keeps a spreadsheet of candidate data, which includes the resume of each candidate inserted as an object. How can we insert multiple objects (resumes) at one time, instead of going through the **Insert --> Object --> Create from File --> Display as icon** individual method we've been using? I've used macros to do that for inserting hyperlinks to docs, but can't figure out one for this or find an answer to a similar question. Please help!

Comment: Start recording a macro do what you want and you should have a basic macro to add objects.  Set it in a loop the same way you would for adding hyperlinks and that should be it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible use macro for it. For example:

http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-addinsert-multiple-objects-from-a-folder-in-an-excel-document/

Maybe some Excel extension provides this functionality.

I must little modify linked macro (for Excel 2013), but all credits belongs to the original author.

```
Sub AddOlEObject()

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook

Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

Folderpath = "D:\Insert"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count

    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files

    For Each fls In listfiles

        Counter = Counter + 1

        Range("A" & Counter).Value = fls.Name

        strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)

        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then

            ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=strCompFilePath, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconIndex:=1, IconLabel:=strCompFilePath).Select

                'Sheets("Object").Activate

            'Sheets("Object").Range("B" & ((Counter - 1) * 3) + 1).Select

        End If

    Next

mainWorkBook.Save

End Sub
```

Commented lines causes macro crash (Excel 2013), so i disable them. They are for object positioning - so without them, all object are in upper left corner (last over previously inserted).

Sorry for bad English.